# Overwriting Existing Python Plots with New Function Call

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I would like to overwrite an existing plot I made in python with a new function call. I would like to produce a plot, look at it, then call the same function again with different arguments to produce another plot. I would like the second plot to replace the first plot. That is, I don't want two figure windows open; just the original window overwritten.

I have tried using interactive mode when plotting (ion()), placing plot() and show() calls in different places, and clearing figures. The problems I have are that: 1. I can never overwrite and existing window, I always open more 2. show() blocks the code from continuing and I am unable to perform the 2nd function call 3. I use interactive mode and the window appears for a second before going away

What I'm trying to do seems simple enough, but I'm having great difficulty. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

## Easiest solution

There are many ways to do this, the easiest of which is to reset the plot's `Line2D` using its `set_ydata(...)` method and `pyplot.pause`. There are versions of matplotlib (<0.9, I believe) which don't have `pyplot.pause`, so you may need to update yours. Here's a simple minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ph, = plt.plot(np.random.rand(100))

def change_plot():
    ph.set_ydata(np.random.rand(100))
    plt.pause(1)

while True:
    change_plot()
```

## Other approaches

1. Using `pyplot.ion` and `pyplot.ioff`, as detailed [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode). I tend to use these when I'm doing exploratory data analysis with a Python shell.
2. Using the `matplotlib.animation` package, as detailed in [this very comprehensible example](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/basic_example.html). This is a much more robust approach than the easy solution above, and permits all kinds of useful/fun options, such as outputting the animation to a video file, etc.
3. Instead of using the `set_ydata` method of the Lines object, you can always clear the axes (`pyplot.cla()`) and call the plotting command again. For example, if you are using `pyplot.contour`, the returned `QuadContourSet` has no `set_zdata` method, but this will work:

   ```
   import numpy as np
   from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

   X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(100),np.arange(100))

   def change_plot():
       Z = np.random.random(X.shape)
       plt.cla()
       ph = plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
       plt.pause(1)

   while True:
       change_plot()
   ```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am making a contour plot with "contourf()". I will be changing the z-data; is there any corresponding set_zdata() for contour plots? I can't find any after a quick search.

Comment: No, I don't believe so. The object returned by `plt.contour` is a `QuadContourSet`. You can achieve the same behavior by extracting all of the lines from its `collections` property, and handling them as you need to. However, it might be simpler to use `plt.cla()` and `plt.contour(...)` in the `change_plot()` function, to clear the axes and redraw the contour, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

write your plotting function like

```
def my_plotter(ax, data, style):
    ax.cla()
    # ax.whatever for the rest of your plotting
    return artists_added
```

and then call it like

```
data = some_function()
arts = my_plotter(plt.gca(), data, ...)
```

or do

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

and then call your plotting function like

```
arts = my_plotter(ax, data, ...)
```

Comment: I believe I understand your example. "arts" will hold the new axes we made with "my_plotter" and whatever "data" we input. But, how can I view the newly created axes object and re-call my_plotter() without show() blocking the interpreter?

Comment: No, you pass am axes in, arts is the artists created in your function

Comment: Okay, maybe I don't understand matplotlib structures too well. I can clear the axes with ax.cla(), then I put something into it with ax.contourf(...), then return ax, which I can then plot. I guess my problem is with using show() in that it blocks the interpreter from continuing and from me calling my_plotter again.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same issue and I solved it by assigning a name for each plot.

```
def acc(train_acc, test_acc, savename):
    plt.figure(savename) # If you remove this line, the plots will be added to the same plot. But, when you assign a figure, each plot will appear in a separate plot.
    ep = np.arange(len(train_acc)) + 1

    plt.plot(ep, train_acc, color="blue", linewidth=1, linestyle="-", label="Train")
    plt.plot(ep, test_acc, color="red",  linewidth=1, linestyle="-", label="Test")
    plt.title("NDCG")
    plt.xlabel("Iteration")
    plt.ylabel("NDCG@K")
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    plt.savefig(savename)
```